# Сага (ServiceBus) и несколько серверов-обработчиков

Tags: cqrs

Здравствуйте!
Помогите разобраться с такой концепцией как "Сага" (Saga, Process Manager). А именно - не могу представить, как это дело должно работать на нескольких обрабатывающих серверах.

Например, создаётся инициирующее сообщение, отправляется в очередь, и на одном из серверов (кто первый взял это сообщение из очереди (RabbitMQ, MSSQ или что-то ещё) создаётся новый инстанс "Саги". Теперь она будет висеть в памяти этого сервера, или просто сохранит свое состояние в БД и объект саги на этом сервере уничтожится, чтобы возродиться на другом сервере, который получит следующее сообщения для этой саги?

Если будет висеть в памяти сервера, то нужно как-то обеспечить, чтобы все следующие сообщения для этой саги попали именно на этот сервер?

Присматриваюсь к Rebus и MassTransit, но не нашел в документации и примерах описание такого кейса.

Расскажите о своем опыте применения этой концепции при условии наличия множества серверов, которые могут обрабатывать сообщения из очереди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Варианты:

1. Сага каждый раз восстанавливает свое состояние из хранилища, обрабатывает сообщение, сохраняет состояние и умирает. Т.о. ноды являются stateless.
2. Организуется партиционирование сообщений, чтобы все сообщения, относящиеся к одной сущности/процессу, попадали на один и тот же сервер. С этим вариантом сложнее, поскольку, во-первых, нужно, чтобы сама логика допускала такого рода партиционирование (например, по ID сущности), и, во-вторых, чтобы очередь сообщений поддерживала партиционирование (не могу сказать, возможно ли это в упомянутых вами системах, поскольку не работал с ними). Т.о. ноды являются stateful, но гарантируется, что нужные сообщения попадут на нужную ноду. При этом нужно учесть сценарий, при котором нода упадет, и новое сообщение попадет на другую ноду, которая ничего не знает о текущем состоянии саги, которая должна обрабатывать это сообщение.
3. Гибридный вариант, когда партиционирование отсутствует, саги хранятся в памяти, но каждый раз проверяется, не устарело ли их состояние.